# return arrays as array of 2 elements instead of 4 ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a simple each statement on an array

```
game.each{|match|  winner += rps_game_winner(match)
```

winner is previously defined as `winner = []`

rps_game_winner will return an array of 2 elements.
I want the winner to be and array of an array of 2 elements.
instead if game has 2 matches i will get an array for 4 elements.

Is there a way to quickly convert an array of 4 elements to an array with 2 arrays of 2 elements.
Or to make winners an array of 2 elements in the first place

for example winners should equal [["rob","Hi"],["sally","no"]] instead of ["rob","Hi","sally","no"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `+=`; use `<<`:

```
game.each{|match| winner << rps_game_winner(match)}
```

While `+` combines two arrays into one, `<<` adds new elements. If a new element happens to itself be another array, it's still added as an element, not merged in.

If you prefer words to punctuation, you can also spell it `push`:

```
game.each do |match| winner.push(rps_game_winner match) end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `each_cons`, which means each consecutive elements:

```
game.each_cons(2){|match1,match2| 
    winner << [rps_game_winner(match1), rps_game_winner(match2)]
}
```

*NB: the use of each_cons works fine if rps_game_winner would return a flat element, not an array with two elements

Answer (score 1):

You want [`#each_slice`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/frames). This returns an enumerable method which you can iterate over, but calling `#to_a` on it will convert it into the array you want:

```
["rob","Hi","sally","no"].each_slice(2).to_a # => [["rob", "Hi"], ["sally", "no"]]
```